# What are good practices of making code faster?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Problem statement: [Sherlock and the Valid String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-valid-string/problem)

This code passes all tests for correctness, 15/20, however, some tests are failing because of the time limits. 
What are good practices about making code faster? How can `for` loops be avoided?

```
static String isValid(String s) {

    String yesOrNo;
    //Step 1: count the frequency of each char and out in a map <char, number>
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < s.length(); c++) {
            if (s.charAt(c) == s.charAt(i))
                count++;
        }
        map.put(s.charAt(i), count);
    }
    //Step2: add all the numbers of occurrences of each char into a list
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> kv : map.entrySet()
    ) {
        values.add(kv.getValue());
    }
    //Step 3: find the benchmark number
    Map<Integer, Integer> occurPairs = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        occurPairs.put(values.get(i), Collections.frequency(values, values.get(i)));
    }
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> popVal = Collections.max(occurPairs.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> smallest = Collections.min(occurPairs.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

    //Step 4: compare each value with the benchmark
    int numOfWrong = 0;
    for (Integer value : values) {
        if (!value.equals(popVal.getKey()))
            numOfWrong += Math.abs(popVal.getKey() - value);
    }
    if (occurPairs.size() == 2 && smallest.getValue() == 1 && smallest.getKey() == 1)
        yesOrNo = "YES";
    else if (numOfWrong > 1)
        yesOrNo = "NO";
    else
        yesOrNo = "YES";
    System.out.println(yesOrNo);
    return yesOrNo;
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing a lot of extra work to check if the string is invalid. If any other frequencies are different by more than 1, you can return false right then with no additional comparisons.

Comment: Do you know what Big-O complexity is? If not we can explain it in our answers.

Comment: @NomadMaker HR wants me to return a String. There is no real rest of ***my*** code, as this is the only method I input, and then HR does the rest.

Comment: @JohnKugelman this would be very helpful. I'd like to learn some new content if you have time to explain.

Comment: @Tyberius I can't agree with "any", if you read the requirement, it says that 

Sherlock considers a string to be valid if all characters of the string appear the same number of times. It is also valid if he can remove just  1 character at 1  index in the string, and the remaining characters will occur the same number of times. Given a string , determine if it is valid. If so, return YES, otherwise return NO.

Comment: That's exactly my point. 1. Get all the frequencies 2. Pick one for comparisons 3. If any other frequencies is different by two or more (more than 1 char would need to be removed), than the string is invalid and you are done. You need more checks to determine for sure if a string is valid, but you can more quickly determine that a string is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I won't tell you outright what's wrong but I'll give you a conceptual framework by which you can analyze your code.

Think about the number of steps you perform per letter in the input string.

- If you perform a fixed number of steps then you'll get **linear** scaling. Let's say you do three steps per letter. If there are *n* letters and you perform *3n* operations, you're in good shape.
- However, if you perform *n* operations per letter then you'll get **quadratic** scaling with *n²* or *3n²* or operations in total. (The constant in front is not important. It's the exponent that matters.) Let's say you have 1,000 letters. *3n* scaling would mean 3 thousand operations. *3n²* scaling would mean 3 *million*.

Quadratic basically means "doesn't scale". Instead of scaling in proportion to the input length, quadratic algorithms blow up when the input gets large. They work fine for normal workloads but fall apart when under pressure. Hacker Rank is very likely throwing really long input strings at your algorithm to detect quadratic blowup.

I talked about *n* above. In Java lingo *n* is `s.length()`. Can you spot the quadratic step in your code where you are performing `s.length() * s.length()` operations?

> Yes, in step 1 I'm iterating twice over the `s` to count the frequency of each char.

That's right. Good. Now, how could you do step 1 in a single pass?

Think about how you'd do it on paper. You wouldn't scan the string over and over and over and over and over, right? You'd just look at each letter once and keep a running count of all the letters as you go. You'd probably have a table with letters and tally marks like:

```
A   ||||
B   
C   |
D   ||
E   |||||||
F   
...
```

Do the same in code and it'll cut the *n²* down to *n*.

Comment: Thank you so much! 

I found this on SO, @JohnKugelman, passes everything. 
s.chars().forEach(e->map.put((char)e, map.getOrDefault((char)e, 0) + 1));

Comment: Yep, that'll work. I'll challenge you to write it yourself so it's not 'magic'. It should only take a slight modification to your existing code.

Comment: ok, I'll spend another minute to review it for a simpler solution. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JohnKugelman answer, here is what you can do.

First of all, you are going through your string twice (with inner loop) to count the occurrences which is O(n^2). You already found a O(n) solution for that

```java
Map<Character, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<>();

s.chars()
 .forEach(e-> occurences.put((char)e, occurences.getOrDefault((char)e, 0) + 1));
```

Now we need to find a simple iteration to find out the answer.

Here are what we know about the `"YES"` cases.

- All of the letters have same frequency e.g: aabbccddeeff
- All of the letters have same frequency but a single letter which occurs 1 time more. e.g: aabbccddd
- All of the letters have same frequency but a single letter with 1 occurrence. e.g: aaaabbbbcccce

So what we need to do is to go through values of our map and count the number of occurrences.

First, let's get our iterator

```java
Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> iterator = occurences
                .entrySet()
                .iterator();
```

Then choose first number as "benchmark" and define a variable and a count for first different value

```java
int benchmark = iterator.next().getValue();
int benchmarkCount = 1;
int firstDifferent = -1;
int differentCount = 0;
```

Iterate through the numbers

```java
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    int next = iterator.next().getValue();
    if (next == benchmark) { // if the next number is same
        benchmarkCount++; // just update our count
    } else { // if it is different
        // if we haven't found a different one yet or it is the same different value from earlier
        if (firstDifferent == -1 || firstDifferent == next) {
            firstDifferent = next;
            differentCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all we need to do is to analyze our numbers

```java
int size = occurences.size();

if (benchmarkCount == size) return "YES"; // if all of the numbers are the same
if (benchmarkCount == size - 1) { // if we hit only single different
    // either the diffent number is 1 or it is greater than our benchmark by value of 1
    if (firstDifferent == 1 || firstDifferent - benchmark == 1) {
        return "YES";
    }
}
// same case with above
if (differentCount == size - 1) {
    if (benchmark == 1 || benchmark - firstDifferent == 1) {
        return "YES";
    }
}
```

Full solution

```java
static String isValid(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<>();

    s.chars().forEach(e-> occurences.put((char)e, occurences.getOrDefault((char)e, 0) + 1));

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> iterator = occurences
            .entrySet()
            .iterator();

    int benchmark = iterator.next().getValue();
    int benchmarkCount = 1;
    int firstDifferent = -1;
    int differentCount = 0;

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        int next = iterator.next().getValue();
        if (next == benchmark) {
            benchmarkCount++;
        } else {
            if (firstDifferent == -1 || firstDifferent == next) {
                firstDifferent = next;
                differentCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    int size = occurences.size();

    if (benchmarkCount == size) return "YES";
    if (benchmarkCount == size - 1) {
        if (firstDifferent == 1 || firstDifferent - benchmark == 1) {
            return "YES";
        }
    }
    if (differentCount == size - 1) {
        if (benchmark == 1 || benchmark - firstDifferent== 1) {
            return "YES";
        }
    }

    return "NO";
}
```

Comment: That's pretty complicated, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find the other solutions far too complicated. Using the number of different characters (`counts.length` below) and their minimum frequency (`min` below), we know that the string length is at least `counts.length * min`.

When a single character occurs once more than `min`, we have a string longer by one.

When there are more such characters, the string gets longer than `counts.length * min + 1`. When any character occurs even more often than `min + 1`, the string gets longer than `counts.length * min + 1`, too.

As noted by  Bunyamin Coskuner, my solution missed cases like "aabbc". This one works but it's no more as simple as wanted:

```
static String isValid(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) return "YES";
    final int[] counts = s.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> c)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(n -> n.intValue())
            .toArray();
    final int min = Arrays.stream(counts).min().getAsInt();
    // Accounts for strings like "aabb" and "aabbb".
    if (s.length() <= counts.length * min + 1) return "YES";
    // Here, strings can be only valid when the minimum is one, like for "aabbc".
    if (min != 1) return "NO";
    final int minButOne = Arrays.stream(counts).filter(n -> n>1).min().getAsInt();
    return s.length() == (counts.length - 1) * minButOne + 1 ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your "simple" solution does not work for all cases. Also, can you tell me what's the complexity of your solution since that's the point of the question?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Sorry, I haven't tested it. Could you provide me with a failing test? `+++` The complexity is the same as yours, linear in `s.length()`. `+++` The only somewhat complicated part in my solution is the collecting line (google for "java stream grouping count").

Comment: It does not work for the cases like "aabbc" in which you can delete "c" to make it a valid string. However, your function returns "NO" because s.length = 5, counts.length = 3, and min = 1

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Thank you.... I'll fix it today. I still think my approach is good, it's just that I should have tested it a bit. My bad.

Comment: I didn't say your approach is bad, but using stream API only does not make a code "good" or "simple".  Also, adding checks for edge-cases made it as complicated as mine and you had to go through the count array one more time at the end. I was referring to your initial comment on my answer. Also, I'm not suggesting mine is perfect either. It could be improved using some parts of your approach.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Agreed. `+++` Concerning the streams, the collecting looks complicated unless you're used to it. The `.values()....` part gets rid of the Map as the `counts` are all we need.  `+++` As I saw your solution, I was sure there must be a simpler solution. I was right with it, but blew my solution.